# using regex for filtering some words in persian in php

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I'm working on a script that is going to identify offensive words from text messages. The problem is that sometimes users make some changes in words and make them unidentifiable. my code has to be able to identify those too as far as possible.

First of all I replace all non-alnum chars to spaces.

And then:
I've written two regex patterns.
One to remove repeating characters from string.
for Example: the user has written: seeeeex, it replaces it with sex:

```
preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', $text)
```

this regex works fine for English words but not in Farsi words which is my case.
for example if you write:
امیییییییییین
it does nothing with it.
I also tried

```
mb_ereg_replace
```

But it didn't work either.

My other regex is to remove spaces around all one-letter words.
for example: I want it to convert S E X to sex:

```
preg_replace('/( [a-zA-Zآ-ی] )\1+/', trim('$1'), $text);
```

This regex doesn't work at all and needs to be corrected.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I suspect it should be `preg_repalce` not `str_replace`.

Comment: @revo right, That was a mistake in asking the question, In my codes I used the preg one

Comment: Try to use Unicode flag `u` => `/(.)\1+/u`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with multi-byte characters, you should enable Unicode Aware modifier to change behavior of tokens in order to match right thing. In your first case it should be:

```
/(.)\1+/u
```

In your second regex, however, I see both syntax and semantic errors which you would change it to:

```
/\b(\pL)\s+/u
```

PHP:

```
preg_replace('/\b(\pL)\s+/u', '$1', $text);
```

Putting all together:

```
$text = 'سسس ککک سسس';
echo preg_replace(['/(.)\1+/u', '/\b(\pL)\s+/u'], '$1', $text); // خروجی میدهد: سکس
```

**[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/cj97R)**

Comment: Thank you, It was great, Just one more thing, In the second regex The last letter of the word with has spaces around it, attaches to the next word, Like this sentence: من خیلی س ک س را دوست دارم becomes 'من خیلی سکسرا دوست دارم' after replacement. How do I fix this?

Comment: A simple workaround would be changing `\b(\pL)\s+` to `\b(\pL)\s+(?!\S{2})`

Comment: I got this error:  ERROR: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Don't forget to put delimiters.